# FontAwesome - Manual Stacking

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, font-awesome

I am trying to manually stack Soundcloud icon and show it on a square as it is with [`fa-facebook-square`](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/facebook-square/), but my Soundcloud icon get created under the square.

This is my code so far:

```
<div class="row">
    <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0px; padding-left: 20px;">
        <li style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
             <div style="float: left; margin-right: 10px; width: 15px; text-align: center; color: #ff3a00">
                <i class="fa fa-square fa-1x" style="font-size: 14px; position: relative; z-index: 10"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-soundcloud fa-1x fa-inverse" style="font-size: 8px; position: absolute; z-index: 11; margin-top: 3px; margin-left: 1px"></i>
              </div>Soundcloud
        </li>
        <li style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <div style="float: left; margin-right: 10px; width: 15px; text-align: center; color: #3b5998;">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
            </div>Facebook
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/gvdr7889/

If there is any other alternative/easier way, I am open for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `margin-top` and `margin-left`, use `top` and `left`.  I used `5px` and `7px`, but you can adjust it to get the positioning you like.

http://jsfiddle.net/gvdr7889/1/

Comment: Looks cool in the jsfiddle however, in my case, social icons are located in a different section, so giving it a manual top & left would mess things up. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Always display the icon in a parent element with `position: relative`, and you should be good.  http://jsfiddle.net/gvdr7889/2/

Comment: Or, set `margin-top: -15px; margin-left: -5px;`.  http://jsfiddle.net/gvdr7889/3/

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ieuank/4e77mmj1/) fiddle.
What I've done is change it so that the div you made is the background, which has the orange-red color, the size and the border radius. Then the normal `fa-soundcloud fa-1x fa-inverse` in it in white. Might have to play around with the sizes and colors, but it seems to me like that is what you're looking for.

There is also a [Github issue](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/5485) requesting a proper `soundcloud-square` icon, I'd suggest letting them know you want it too over there